# Extracting substring in the middle of text under different conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have strings in a column that contain persons' middle initials and last names that I need to extract. The name always appears after "Referral to " text. However, the text can end with the last name or it can have a second part that begins with " (". For example,

Option 1: "Referral to J. Smith"

Option 2: "Referral to S. James (1st priority)"

There can be variations of text before and after, e.g.

Option 1a: "Urgent Referral to J. Smith"

Option 2a: "Referral to S. James (TBD)"

The text I needed extracted is always located after "Referral to " and sometimes also before " ("

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Regarding regular expressions: The site [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) provides a great way to test a regex. It also provides a (sometimes cryptic but often very clear) explanation of how the regex works. There is also a cheat sheet. Be aware that the [Google Scripts flavor of regex](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en) is not completely compatible with the more common PCRE flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach which does not use a regex to parse names from strings:

```js
// array of data extracted from the sheet:
var strings = [ 
  'Referral to J. Smith', 
  'Referral to S. James (1st priority)',
  'Urgent Referral to J. Smith',
  'Referral to S. James (TBD)'
];

var minBoundary = 'Referral to ';
var maxBoundary = ' (';

strings.forEach((str) => { 
  var min = str.indexOf(minBoundary) + minBoundary.length;
  var max = str.lastIndexOf(maxBoundary);
  max = (max < 0) ? str.length : max;
  var name = str.substring(min, max);
  console.log(name);
} );
```

This searches for the location of the starting boundary text, and ending boundary text. For the ending boundary, that is either the location of the final  `(`, or the end of the string if there is no  `(`.

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames. One thing that my script does is it is looking row by row, extract the name of the person, retrieve their e-mail address form another sheet and sends an e-mail. So, I don't need to extract all the names, just the one in the current row that "for (var i in data) {...}" looks at. 

I tried using just the parts for the boundaries, but they didn't work indexOf(minBoundary) has issues. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank youl

Comment: What is the exact data value you had a problem with? `indexOf(minBoundary)` assumes there is always a substring containing `Referral to ` in every value (based on the description given in the question). If there are variations of that, then the code may need to be adjusted. So, for example if its `referral to ` or `Ref. to `, then those would need to be handled differently in the code.

Comment: Thank you, @andrewjames - all worked perfectly, I just needed to tweak it a bit to work within my for loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexextract() function in google sheets.

Try this formula below:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\w\. \w+")
```

Comment: Hi Jason,
It works!! Thank you. I am not sure what the "\w\. \w+" part does. I tried regextract, but with no success. I thought regular expression is the exact text I need to extract. That "\w\. \w+" does the magic to get the name out. How does it work?!!

Comment: Hi @MikeB. regex or regular expression is a sequence of characters that specifies a search pattern. In this case, the \w that we used is called a meta character which represents a single word/non-word letter/character. In short, we are telling the regexextract() to search for a pattern of [single-character].[space][set of characters]. You can learn more about regex here https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a cleaner way to do it with Regex, but this might work in row 2 of an otherwise empty column if your strings are in column A starting at row 2.

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(MID(A2:A,FIND("Referral to",A2:A)+12,100)," (",0)),,1)
```

Comment: Hi MattKing, thank you for the suggestion. I placed the actual text sample "Tech-Internet need: Referral to J. Smith" in cell A2 and placed your formula in B2 and I got an empty cell. I'm not exactly sure what the formula does, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: @MikeB. Apologies, it was hard to do blind without a sample sheet.  I made one here.  You were right there was a typo in my formula.  I've since edited it and it seems to work fine. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c5EIWmBt4yOsIxUSvqZF4giRSgTsBqBo5F6w_uuEZLI/edit#gid=2100307022

Answer (score 1):

A simple `regexextract` can do this. In case there are multiple initials or hyphenated names, try:

`=arrayformula(if(A1:A<>"",regexextract(A1:A,"to (\w[\w\. -]+\w+)"),))`

The `arrayformula` allows the `regexextract` to run down the sheet, whilst Col `A` has a value `A1:A<>""`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInitials() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();//all of my strings were in column one
  let iA = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    iA.push({row: i+1,initials: [...r[0].toString().matchAll(/[A-Z]{1,}\.{1,}/g)].map(e => e[0].split("")[0]).join(',')});
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(iA));
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Execution log
5:29:05 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:29:07 PM  Info    [{"row":1,"initials":"J,P,J,J"},{"row":2,"initials":"J,P,J,J"},{"row":3,"initials":"J,P,J,J"},{"row":4,"initials":"J,P,J,J"},{"row":5,"initials":"J,P,J,J"},{"row":6,"initials":"J,P,J,J"},{"row":7,"initials":"J,P,J,J"},{"row":8,"initials":"J,P,J,J"}]
5:29:07 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your original strings were in A2:A, place this in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A&"(","to ([^(]+)"))))`

The benefit of this particular method over perhaps others is that it will also extract names with apostrophes and foreign characters (e.g., F. O'Donald, J. Muñoz, C. Adriáno, etc.).

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for the suggestion. I placed the actual text sample "Tech-Internet need: Referral to J. Smith" in cell A2 and placed your formula in B2 and I got Formula parse Error. I'm not exactly sure what the formula does, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: My formula is written to process the entire column A:A, not A2 or A2:A. Try changing A:A to A2:A and see if that works. If not, then you may be in a country that uses semicolons where the US uses commas. What is your locale? It is always most efficient to share a link to a sample spreadsheet. There is much that can only be assessed by seeing your actual sheet, locale, data, layout, etc.

Comment: Also, are you using Google Sheets? Or are you trying to work with an Excel file that's in your Google Drive?